# Telerik RadNumericTextBox value from Code behind c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I access the values entered by a user in a Tekerik RadNumericTextBox  from the code behind on an ASPX page within a table with out using Ajax? I need to save them to one table in a database, possibly using a databind? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<telerik:RadPanelItem Enabled="false" Text="Step 4: Goals" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadPanelItem Value="Goals" runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="formEntry-fb">
                    <ul id="goalInfo">
                        <li>
                         <asp:Repeater ID="rptGoals" runat="server">

                            <div style="float: left;">
                                <label class="textLabel right">Goals</label>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: inline-block;">
                                <div class="RadListView RadListView_Silk ">

                                        <headertemplate>
                                            <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;" border="0">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr id="headerRow" runat="server" class="rlvHeader">
                                                        <th>Goal</th>
                                                        <th>Expected result
                                                        </th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                        </headertemplate>
                                        <itemtemplate>
                                            <tr class="rlvI">
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblGoal" CssClass="textLabel" runat="server" Text="Interactions"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                     <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtInteractions" runat="server" MinValue="1" MaxValue="100000" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" DataType="System.Int32" ShowSpinButtons="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="AttendeesChanged" Value="1"></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rlvI">

                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAppointments" CssClass="textLabel" runat="server" Text="Appointments"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                     <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtAppointments" runat="server" MinValue="1" MaxValue="100000" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" DataType="System.Int32" ShowSpinButtons="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="AttendeesChanged" Value="1"></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rlvI">
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustomersAssessment" CssClass="textLabel" runat="server" Text="Customer Needs Assessment"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                     <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtCustomerAssessment" runat="server" MinValue="1" MaxValue="100000" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" DataType="System.Int32" ShowSpinButtons="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="AttendeesChanged" Value="1"></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rlvI">
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCheckingAccount" CssClass="textLabel" runat="server" Text="Checking Accounts"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                     <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtCheckingAccounts" runat="server" MinValue="1" MaxValue="100000" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" DataType="System.Int32" ShowSpinButtons="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="AttendeesChanged" Value="1"></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="rlvI">
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSolutions" CssClass="textLabel" runat="server" Text="Solutions"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                     <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtSolutions" runat="server" MinValue="1" MaxValue="100000" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" DataType="System.Int32" ShowSpinButtons="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="AttendeesChanged" Value="1"></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </itemtemplate>
                                        <footertemplate>
                                            </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                        </footertemplate>
                                      </asp:Repeater>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get your 'txtInteractions' value

```
//First .Value returns the nullable decimal or double
txtInteractions.Value

//second .Value gets the decimal or double in non-nullable form
txtInteractions.Value.Value
```

Comment: The table or RadPanelItem will not let me access any of the numberic text boxes it in the code behind, Im afraid Im going to have to use jquery. Ive researched the Telerik site and I know someone has done it but just can't find the answer and im not very good with Jquery.